# Comparação de resultado BigDecimal com Float (Java)

Tags: java, matemática

**Tenho duas fórmulas implementadas, uma com o tipo BigDecimal e outra com o tipo double primitivo, mas os resultados divergem e eu não tou conseguindo encontrar a solução. Segue abaixo as fórmulas:**

```
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(3.2d); //TODO: entradas do usuário
BigDecimal t = new BigDecimal(365d);
/**
 * Convertendo valor de v para m/d
 */
//double Vmd = v * Math.pow(10d, -2d);
BigDecimal Vmd = new BigDecimal(v * Math.pow(10d, -2d));
/**
 * convertendo valor de W para m/d
 */
//double Wmd = W / 100d;
BigDecimal Wmd = new BigDecimal(W / 100d);
BigDecimal div = new BigDecimal(1d/2d);
BigDecimal teste = div.multiply(new BigDecimal(Math.exp(primeiroTermo.doubleValue()))).
                     multiply(new BigDecimal( Erf.erfc(seguntoTermo.doubleValue())).add(div)
                    .multiply(new BigDecimal(Math.exp(terceiroTermo.doubleValue())))
                    .multiply(new BigDecimal(Erf.erfc(quartoTermo.doubleValue()))));

System.out.println("Valor total de Bxt em BigDecimal: " + nb.format(teste));

Bxt = (1d/2d) * (Math.exp(primeiroTermo.doubleValue())) * Erf.erfc(seguntoTermo.doubleValue()) + (1d/2d) * (Math.exp(terceiroTermo.doubleValue())) * Erf.erfc(quartoTermo.doubleValue());

System.out.println("Valor de BXT: em Double " + nb.format(Bxt));
```

**Valor Final:**

```
Valor total de Bxt em BigDecimal: 1,63E6
Valor de BXT: em Double 6,41E-20
Valor esperado : 6,19E-20
```

**Valores dos termos: (valores da entrada paras formulas)**

```
valor do primeiro termo : -1,75E0
valor do segundo termo :6.31838147917065306052600332590254032941338413886611227745342947009953030493273342105799365116070956364
valor do terceiro termo :1,74E1
valor do quartoTermo termo :7.68858730163961471709076409364321640056053538848914223720418242638997018233141713029583833874949308593
```

**O resultado mais proximo do correto é o do double primitivo**

Comment: O que que é o `div`?

Comment: Há ainda outro erro: a expressão com o double tem um factor de 1/2 e a do BigDecimal não.

Comment: Alexandre a váriavel div é o que faz esse 1/2

Comment: @Math é o 1/2 que tem na outra formula

Comment: Nunca utilizai nada disso, mas creio que o erro está na forma como estás a aplicar incorrectamente o método add. Experimenta separares a variável teste em dois termos e somá-los posteriormente à parte.

Comment: Vê também isto: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944559/how-to-multiply-a-bigdecimal-by-an-integer-in-java

Comment: Essa questão que você me indicou eu já utilizo.  :(

Comment: Tem a certeza? Porque parece que está a fazer teste=((1/2*termo_a*termo_b) + 1/2) * termo_c * termo_4 e não o que pretende...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema nesse caso é que você alterou a precedência dos operadores, e consequentemente está obtendo outro valor.

Simplificando, seu código está assim:

```
public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer primeiroTermo = 5;
        Integer segundoTermo = 6;
        Integer terceiroTermo = 7;
        Integer quartoTermo = 8;

        BigDecimal div = new BigDecimal(1d/2d);
        BigDecimal teste = div.multiply(new BigDecimal(primeiroTermo.doubleValue()))
                            .multiply(new BigDecimal(segundoTermo.doubleValue()).add(div)
                            .multiply(new BigDecimal(terceiroTermo.doubleValue()))
                            .multiply(new BigDecimal(quartoTermo.doubleValue())));

        System.out.println("Valor total de Bxt em BigDecimal: " + teste);

        Double Bxt =
                (1d/2d) * primeiroTermo.doubleValue() * segundoTermo.doubleValue() + 
                (1d/2d) * terceiroTermo.doubleValue() * quartoTermo.doubleValue();

        System.out.println("Valor de BXT: em Double " + Bxt);
    }
}
```

Perceba que para o caso do Double você faz duas multiplicações e depois soma com mais duas multiplicações, já no caso do BigInteger você multiplica o `terceiroTermo` e o `quartoTermo` com o resultado das primeiras multiplicações.

Para consertar fica assim:

```
BigDecimal teste = (div.multiply(new BigDecimal(primeiroTermo.doubleValue()))
                    .multiply(new BigDecimal(segundoTermo.doubleValue())).add((div)
                    .multiply(new BigDecimal(terceiroTermo.doubleValue()))
                    .multiply(new BigDecimal(quartoTermo.doubleValue()))));
```

Perceba que eu inseri um `)` a mais logo antes do `.add`, que fecha o novo `(` antes do `div.multiply`, e inseri também um `(` logo após o `.add`, que é fechado no final da sentença.

Para o meu exemplo simplificado acima, o resultado é:

> Valor total de Bxt em BigDecimal: 43.0
>   Valor de BXT: em Double 43.0

[Veja funcionando no Ideone](https://ideone.com/8AmwSo).

Deixando a minha simplificação de lado e colocando as correções no seu código, substitua o trecho que calcula o resultado de `teste` pelo trecho a seguir:

```
BigDecimal teste = (div.multiply(new BigDecimal(Math.exp(primeiroTermo.doubleValue()))).
        multiply(new BigDecimal( Erf.erfc(seguntoTermo.doubleValue()))).add((div)
       .multiply(new BigDecimal(Math.exp(terceiroTermo.doubleValue())))
       .multiply(new BigDecimal(Erf.erfc(quartoTermo.doubleValue())))));
```

Comment: Vou dar-te +1 amanhã (excedi o meu número de votos por hoje). Mas aproveito para comentar que, por uma questão de legibilidade e de minorar a probabilidade de erro, teria sido preferível que o AP tivesse separado os dois termos. Assim não necessitaria de andar às voltas com os parêntesis.

Comment: Ah sim, um ponto negativo da imutabilidade é justamente esse, torna o código de difícil compreensão e exige que se separe as coisas com mais cuidados para tentar descomplicar um pouco. PS: você vota pra caramba hein, rs.

Comment: Hoje passei tempo em demasia no forum...

Comment: @JoseVieiraNeto Ah, o primeiro código é o errado, você tem que substituir o trecho do final para dar certo.

Comment: @Math ainda não tá rolando :(

Comment: @Math foi eu vi . erro meu desculpe.

Comment: @Math mas eu fiz no principal eu não funcionou chegou mais perto mas n funcionou :(

Comment: @Math quer dá uma olhada na minha classe completa ?

Comment: @JoseVieiraNeto olha a minha resposta atualizada, mudei o último paragrafo.

Comment: @Math muito obrigado agora os dois resultados tão iguais pelo menos. agora eu não entendo por que o valor final diverge de : 6,19E-20 está dando 6,41E-20

Comment: @JoseVieiraNeto Diverge pouco... Para descobrires a razão disso terás de ver como é que o valor esperado foi calculado.

Comment: @AlexandreCartaxo entendo . eu vou criar outra pergunta pra vcs entenderem melhor

Comment: @AlexandreCartaxo, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105192/aumentar-precis%C3%A3o-com-bigdecimal-java

Comment: @Math, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105192/aumentar-precis%C3%A3o-com-bigdecimal-java

Comment: +1 como prometido.