# Aumentar Precisão com BigDecimal Java

Tags: java, matemática

**Entradas**

```
R = new BigDecimal(2.79E+00);
Dxm3d = new BigDecimal(3.99E-04);
Wmd = new BigDecimal(2.39E-03);
x = new BigDecimal(3.2);
t = new BigDecimal(365);
```

**Segue abaixo a fórmula**

```
BigDecimal segundoTermo = (R.multiply(x).subtract(Wmd.multiply(t)).divide(new BigDecimal(2d).multiply(new BigDecimal(Math.sqrt(Dxm3d.multiply(R).multiply(t).doubleValue()))), RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN));
System.out.println("valor do segundo termo pfv:" + segundoTermo);
```

**Valor retornado**

```
valor do segundo termo pfv:6.31838147917065306052600332590254032941338413886611227745342947009953030493273342105799365116070956364
```

**Valor Esperado**

```
6,321092458
```

**Esses valores J263 é as cédulas do execel que representam minhas váriaveis.**

- J253 valor: 2,39E-03 representa o Wmd
- J254 valor: 3,99E-04 representa o Dxm3d
- J255 valor: 2,79E+00 representa o R
- I259 valor: 365 representa o t
- J263 valor : 3,2 representa o x

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como é que encontraste o valor esperado?

Comment: Ah. é por que essas formulas foram feitam por uma equipe de engenheiros aqui . que já tem um progama chamando mathcad que faz.

Comment: Tenho um excel aqui tbm e dá o valor esperado certinho.

Comment: Você tem certeza que a fórmula está calculando o que você quer que ela calcule, sem erros de precedência de operadores?

Comment: @Math vou editar a perguntar colocando as prints das formulas e resultados me passado.

Comment: @Math dei uma editada . com os valores fixos dos parametros e a formula onde me baseio para passar pro java . mesmo assim o resultado não retorna o esperado

Comment: José, você poderia por favor mostrar todos os valores (`R`,`x`, `Wmd`, `Dxm3d`, etc)? De preferência apenas atualize o seu código com a declaração / atribuição de cada variável para que possamos simplesmente copiar e colar para verificar o exemplo.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly é pq essas váriaveis já dependem de outros valores anteriores ai eu teria que passa a classe completa mas eu coloquei os valores fixos de cada váriaveis lá em baixo da pergunta . pode trocar os nomes das váriaveis por esses valores que eu coloquei

Answer (score 2):

De forma muito sucinta:

O Mathcad (ou outros programas) usam um diferente número de algarismos significativos tanto para os cálculos como para os valores da função erro. Os valores para a função usados por `Erf.java` estão [aqui](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/jacoco/org.apache.commons.math3.special/Erf.java.html) e utilizam uma implementação de acordo com [isto](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html).

Comment: Eu entendo mas eu tenho um Array de resultados que fazem essas mesmas fórmulas e o resultado final bate é correto. só que no decorrer do loop vai tendo arrendondamentos que perdem a precisão e vai dirvegindo o resultado. esse que to mandando é o indice 4 dos indices os anteriores funcionam

Comment: @JoseVieiraNeto Quanto é que dá erf(1) em java?

Comment: Eu testei as funções de erro. separadamente e batem como mesmo valor do mathcad ou excel o problema está de fato na formula ou precisão dos resultados.

Comment: fiz exatamente isso teste com o valor 1 em java e testei tbm no mathcad e no excel . ambos dão o mesmo resultado

Comment: Porque é que estás a usar RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN?

Comment: por algum motivo ele está me obrigando a ter um RoudingMode. existem vários. testei com todos ambos dão o mesmo resultado

Comment: Já experimentaste reduzir a precisão do BIgDecimal e fazer um arredondamento "normal"?

Comment: Eu estou com o Alexandre nessa de que os valores de entrada estão sendo ajustados. Eu alterei seu exemplo para usar uma precisão de 1000. Me livrei de todos os `doubles`, inclusive o da raiz quadrada (veja: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17306433/664577) e arredondei para cima todas as vezes. A variação no resultado foi de ~ 0.0005 - http://ideone.com/iajyM9. Eu duvido muito que erros de arredondamento nesse caso chegassem a influenciar a segunda casa decimal.

Comment: PS: Para reforçar minha teoria de que as entradas estão diferentes, eis o resultado da fórmula no Excel: http://1drv.ms/1U3ezNm. O resultado da planilha com as entradas que você passou é  `6,318814578`. Isso bate precisamente com as 9 primeiras casas da minha versão no Java.

Answer (score 2):

Minha suspeita é que os valores de entrada estão aproximados e, por isso, causando o desvio no resultado final.

Por exemplo, o valor `2.79E+00` parece ter sido impresso em notação científica com duas casas decimais porque este era o padrão de algum software. Em geral, quando um número de ponto flutuante tem apenas duas casas decimais, notação científica não é adotada.

Para ilustrar o que estou dizendo, adicionais mais algumas casas decimais ao valor de `R` e obtive um valor mais próximo. Veja o exemplo:

```
BigDecimal R = new BigDecimal("2.791654").setScale(20);
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("3.2").setScale(20);
BigDecimal w = new BigDecimal("0.00239").setScale(20);
BigDecimal t = new BigDecimal("365").setScale(20);

//R.x - w.t
BigDecimal dividendo = R.multiply(x).subtract(w.multiply(t));

BigDecimal D = new BigDecimal("0.000399").setScale(20);
BigDecimal dois = new BigDecimal("2").setScale(20);

//2 . (D.R.t) ^ 1/2
BigDecimal divisor = new BigDecimal(Math.sqrt(D.multiply(R).multiply(t).doubleValue())).multiply(dois);

BigDecimal segundoTermo = dividendo.divide(divisor, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
System.out.println("valor do segundo termo pfv:" + segundoTermo);
```

Fiz algumas alterações para deixar o exemplo mais claro, além de adicionar uma quantidade maior de casas decimais, mas tudo isso pouco influencia no resultado final, a não ser a precisão dos números de entrada.

Comment: Amigo muito obrigado pelo retorno. de fato funcionou. mas houve umas alterações nos meu resultados anteriores que estavam corretos kk estou analisando. e jajá te dou um retorno. mais uma vez obrigado.

Comment: e por algum motivo quando eu rodo seu código está dando isso : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Rounding necessary

Comment: Descobri o por que é pq seus valores estão String. por que vc usa essa abordagem ? BigDecimal t = new BigDecimal("365").setScale(20);

Comment: José. Veja meu exemplo no comentário de outra resposta (precisão de 1000 caracteres propagada para todas as operações, os valores iniciais são Strings e não existe nenhum Double intermediário na minha versão). Eu, o utluiz e o Douglas ja apontamos que não é um problema de escala, precisão ou arredondamento. Entre a resposta do utluiz, o ideone e a planilha do Excel  dos meus comentários você já teve três exemplos de que a entrada do seu exemplo são o problema. Confia na gente um pouco e revise suas entradas, o problema não é a escala.

Answer (score 0):

Tendo o valor, um setScale com Round Half Up, deve gerar o resultado que deseja.

```
BigDecimal valor = 123;
BigDecimal resultado = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(valor)).setScale(9, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

Comment: Não funcionou retornou : 6.318381479

Comment: Então é como o @Alexandre disse, a diferença esta em outro lugar

Comment: @JoseVieiraNeto Vê bem a precisão de todas as variáveis. A resposta pode estar por aí.

Comment: Então eu colocando os valores fixos que passei na pergunta dá uma olhada eu editei lá msm assim dá o mesmo valor